# Why declaring funciton with static variables in function arguments is not a error in Windows?

Tags: c++, c

I was reading the documentation about static and other specifiers from

[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and it says

> The static specifier is only allowed in the declarations of variables **(except in function parameter lists  )**, declarations of functions (except at block scope), and declarations of anonymous unions. When used in a declaration of a class member, it declares a static member. When used in a declaration of a variable, it specifies static storage duration (except if accompanied by thread_local). When used in a declaration at namespace scope, it specifies internal linkage.

Now consider a snippet like

```
int test(static int a )
{
     return a;
}

int main()
{

    test(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is complete voilation of the standerd themselves.

This snippet compiles with warning on windows and runs

> C4042: 'a' : has bad storage class

but gives error on Linux ( expected behavior )

> test.cpp:2: error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations
>   test.cpp:2: error: storage class specified for parameter 't'

My question is,
Why does windows compiler allow such type of violations, Do they have any advantage which I cannot see?
How does this behave at run time?
I have few guesses Maybe, none of them is the actual behaviour,
1> static keyword is ignored
2> Multiple copies of this variable a is created whenever the function is called **(calling the function in a loop should crash the program with memory issue.)**
3> Only one static instance is created for the function and every time the fucntion is called the same variable is used **( Calling program in loop will not lead to a crash due to less memory )**

Comment: windows is a mistery

Comment: According to the docs to C4042 it will be replaced with the default storage. I guess MS just ignores the static in this case.

Comment: @PuerNoctis -Isn't that ignoring the stranded themselves, I mean its not that hard to detect this type of usage, do you agree mate?

Comment: @k53sc I totally agree :) But Microsoft is famed for not taking standards too seriously though ;)

Comment: A warning is a diagnostic. That's all that's required by the standard.

Comment: interesting, but if you run the compiled program on windows and see what it will, whether it is possible to get windows compiler output assembler code and see it?

Comment: Just to nitpick. Windows does not have a compiler. Linux does not have a compiler. For both there are many. You have to specify which. And the visual studio compiler is in full accordance with the spec in this case. Just because it does not match your expectations doesn't mean it's broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation, it will be replaced by standard storage class instead. Which is either:

- **extern**, if identifier is a function.
- **auto**, if identifier is a formal parameter or local variable.
- **No storage class**, if identifier is a global variable.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9d31kt4.aspx

GCC 4.8.2 produces the following fatal error:

- error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations
- error: storage class specified for parameter ‘a’

clang 3.5 shows the following fatal compilation error:

- error: invalid storage class specifier in function declaratory
- warning: no previous prototype for function 'test'
  [-Wmissing-prototypes]|

The C++ standard only requires a "diagnostic message" as per section 1.4 [intro.compliance]:

- If a program contains no violations of the rules in this
  International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, within its
  resource limits, accept and correctly execute that program.
- If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an
  occurrence of a construct described in this Standard as
  “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support
  that construct,
  ***a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.***
- If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic
  is required, this International Standard places no requirement on
  implementations with respect to that program.

For this warning I would recommend correcting the code by removing static.