# Static Variable is not maintaing its scope?

Tags: c, static

I was just playing around and wrote this very simple code

```
int main()
{
    static int Z=500;
    printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
    incrementZ(Z);
    printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
    incrementZ(Z);
    printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
}

void incrementZ(static int number)
{
    number++;
}
```

Why static variable is not getting incremented here?

Comment: `void incrementZ(static int number)` does this compile? you're on linux?

Comment: vs2013 and it is compiling.

Comment: ugh. Windows, according to the MSDN documentation, `static` in function argument will be replaced by standard storage class.

Comment: Somehow a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923711/why-declaring-funciton-with-static-variables-in-function-arguments-is-not-a-erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on windows, so check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9d31kt4.aspx).

According to the documentation, the `static` will be replaced by either of the available standard storage class. There are three possible cases,

1. auto : if identifier is a formal parameter or local variable.
2. extern: if identifier is a function.
3. No storage class : if identifier is a global variable.

It will allow the compilation, producing only a warning [C4042] saying something like

> C4042 : identifier .. has bad storage class

---

However, just to add, on linux gcc, this won't complie. It will throw an error saying

> error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `Z`, you're passing its value. The variable `Z` *is* maintaining its scope, i.e. it's not available inside `incrementZ` so nothing happens.

You can of course do this the usual way, i.e. by passing `&Z`.

Also, having `static` on a function argument should not compile, that's not valid C.

Comment: Compiler warning: number has bad storage class?

Answer (score 1):

static variable shouldn't be a parameter to a function.

`Z` is a static variable.So it the scope of `Z` you should be looking at.
If you have static storage class in the function parameter you should see compiler throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

This program would not even compile on `Linux`. It would throw the following error

> **error: storage class specified for parameter ‘number’**

Static variables are stored in the data segment whereas the function arguments are passed on stack.

Windows will not throw error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are just passing the value in Z not not its address. Arguments of a function is also a member of the function. so, the scope of int number is restricted to its function only. Try the following code to get the desired result.

```
    int main()
    {
        static int Z=500;
        printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
        incrementZ(&Z);
        printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
        incrementZ(&Z);
        printf("\n Value of Z is:%d",Z);
    }

void incrementZ(int *number)
{
    *number=*number+1
}
```

int *number is a pointer and incrementZ(&Z) means you are passing the address of Z to number.
* is dereferencing operator used to access the value that number points to.